# How do I convert a .tlb file to headers and implementation files?

Tags: com, idl, mscorlib, typelib, clr-hosting

I'm trying to convert mscorlib.tlb.
It normally used in C++ like this:

```
#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only              \
     high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref")        \
     rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")
```

How can I convert it to headers and implementation files?

I was able to use Visual Studio to compile a dummy cpp file that contained the lines above, and it produced a .tlh file.  Shouldn't there also be implementation files?

Comment: Up vote - told me how to get rid of the warnings for ReportEvent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can split implementation and declaration by using the "no_implementation" and "implementation_only" parameters to #import. These generate .tlh (type library header) and .tli (type library implementation) files.

I typically put the following into a header file (like stdafx.h):

```
#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb" no_implementation
```

And the following into a .cpp file (like stdafx.cpp):

```
#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb" implementation_only
```

Comment: I believe you ment `implementation and DECLARATION` .... not definition.